# Adding count from another table to query with inner join

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM `SAS_applications` 
INNER JOIN `SAS_forms` on SAS_applications.form_id = SAS_forms.fid 
ORDER BY SAS_applications.id DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

and the following SQLite setup:
[image]

This query works fine, but after adding another table to include replies/comments, I ran into some difficulty counting how many comments where a part of each 'application'.

[image]

I'm trying to find a way I can count(*) the amount of entries inside of SAS_comments with the same form_id of each return in the original query, I can achieve this individually by doing

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `SAS_comments` WHERE form_id = 1
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I've tried various joins and nests but my SQL syntax knowledge isn't the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub):

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM SAS_comments WHERE form_id = SAS_forms.fid)
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one more join with SAS_comments, Count and Group By and your code should looks like close to this

```
SELECT 
    count(`SAS_comments`.form_id), `SAS_comments`.id
FROM `SAS_applications` 
INNER JOIN `SAS_forms` on SAS_applications.form_id = SAS_forms.fid 
JOIN `SAS_comments` on `SAS_forms`.form_id = `SAS_comments`.form_id
GROUP BY `SAS_comments`.id
ORDER BY SAS_applications.id DESC
```

Comment: Tried in SQLite browser and got 0 results, only changes `SAS_forms`.form_id to `SAS_forms`.fid, which is the correct column name..

Comment: Try `count(*)` as aggregate and `group by form_id` not comment's unique `id`.

Comment: Also no results.
Here is a DB dump for anyone to play with: https://hastebin.com/kexarofuxe.sql